# Is it possible to assign conditional formatting to a named range in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges

I'd like to apply a conditional formatting rule to a named range. Is that even possible? How do I do that? When trying to enter the Name of the Range to the Field where you set up the range the rule applies to it won't accept my input.

Also with `INDIRECT` it does not work:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom formulas in Sheets conditional formatting, the formula usually accesses a column value in the first row of the format range. Named range values can be used in custom formulas using INDIRECT function.

example from my case ... a list of "brackets" in a tournament. Bracket rows are coloured depending on what bracket the row is for (e.g. brackets 1-10), that value is in the E column.

The formula specifies the appropriate column in the first row of the range (row is relative as conditional formatting iterates over the range).  Since my range is B2:G1005, the formula references cell $E2 (the bracket ID) and compares it to the bracket id stored in a named-range location (*BID_1*), so custom formula is:

**=$E2=INDIRECT("BID_1")**

(if bracket matches the ID assigned to bracket 1 -- colour the cells grey with bolded black text).

[Screenshot of conditional formatting using a named range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90NNj.png)

Answer (score 10):

> [image]

this is not possible in Google Sheets

---

for the custom formula you need to wrap it into `INDIRECT` formula like:

[image: 0]

Comment: Apply the rule to name range! Not use a named rang within the custom formula.

Comment: named range on the picture is **AAA**!

Comment: I want to set up the named range in the "Apply to range" field - ergo - apply the rule to a named range.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible, it is not documented in [official docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

> Range names:
>
> - Can contain only letters, numbers, and underscores.
> - Can't start with a number, or the words "true" or "false."
> - Can't contain any spaces or punctuation.
> - Must be 1–250 characters.
> - Can't be in either A1 or R1C1 syntax. For example, you might get an error if you give your range a name like "A1:B2" or "R1C1:R2C2."

Answer (score 1):

The following works for my specific use case, where the named range is an "unknown" number of rows.

In this case, A1 is a column heading, and is not part of the named range.
A2:A5 is currently assigned to the named range, CitationType.
Conditional formatting is applied to A1:A based on the formula:

```
=and(row(A1)>1,row(A1)<=1+rows(indirect("CitationType")))
```

I did not find an easy way (without scripting) to get the address details of a named range, allowing for "arbitrary" usage in conditional formatting.