# how to apply conditional formatting to a named range?

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

I'm searching for a way in google sheets to use a named range, or preferably by referring to a cell using `INDIRECT()` to specify the range to which the formatting should be conditionally applied.

My approach has been to create a formula in cell A1 which specifies a range, say f1:k10, but which can change dynamically. When I enter `=indirect(A1)` in the box "Apply to range" then I get the error message "Please enter a valid range"

This tells me that Google Sheets doesn't allow named or indirect ranges as the target range which I want to format. I'm hoping that I'm wrong and that there is a nice simple solution?...

I've tried:

```
=indirect(a1)
=indirect ($a$1)
indirect(a1)
=range-name
range-name
```

I've also spent a couple of hours trawling google for an answer

Ideally, when I specify a named range or refer indirectly to a range then I would expect that the specified range will be formatted in accordance with the criteria that I am able to set up in the format rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nope, you are right, Google Sheets does not support referenced ranges in **Apply to range** field.

kind of same as here: 

[Is it possible to assign conditional formatting to a named range in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457493/5632629)